# How to return pg-promise's result back to my controller in Express?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, promise, pg-promise

As I know in RoR, the MVC concept, my controller should get the result from model and after handeling it and render the view, something like this:

```
 def index
    @movies = Movie.all
    if params[:title] || params[:director]
      @movies = Movie.search(params)
    end
  end
```

Now I have an Express server, and I try to structure it in MVC way, using PostgreSQL(pg-promise) and jade.

Currently, I have a controller file with a code as below:

```
//Get home page 
var router = express.Router();
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) { 
  Movies.all(res); 
 });
```

And in my model, I have an all function to handle it:

```
exports.all = function(res){
  var result = db.query('select * from movies').
    then(function (data) {
    // success;
    res.render('index',{title: 'Rotten Mango', movies: data} );
  })
    .catch(function (error) {
      // error;
      console.log('error !')
    });
};
```

But what I want to do is to return the Movies.all's database query result back to my controller like we did in RoR usually or typical MVC way. I imagine something would be like this:

```
//Get home page 
var router = express.Router();
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) { 
    // This code will return the JSON result and render into the view page
    res.render('index', Movies.all );
 });
```

But because this will return an promise or caused by Async ( I am not sure), so I can't make it happen, how could I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this and not pass `res` around as that will make testing hard.

```
exports.all = function(){
   return db.query('select * from movies')
}
```

And in your controller

```
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) { 
  Movies.all()
  .then(function(data) { res.send(data); })
  .catch(function(err) { res.status(500).send(err) }) 
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Simon!!  this helps me figure out! Sometime just have to think in other way in javascript.